# Running ntpq -p command through rspec test for chef

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra, ntp

I'm trying to test ntp settings.
I've provisioned a VM with ntp services installed.
I'm able to login onto the vm and run a command that verifies ntp is indeed installed and restricts queries:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~> sudo ntpq -p
localhost: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

However, when I try to test this exact command in a test, it returns empty...
I'm obviously missing something crucial here, but I cant figure out what.

Here is my test:

```
control 'ntp configuration' do
  describe command('sudo nptq -p') do
    its('stdout') { should match('localhost: timed out, nothing received') }
  end
end
```

And the error:

```
  ×  ntp configuration: Command: `sudo nptq -p`
     ×  Command: `sudo nptq -p` stdout is expected to match "localhost: timed out, nothing received"
     expected "" to match "localhost: timed out, nothing received"
```

I've tried `stdout` and `stderr`, both to no avail.

One thing that I do notice however, is that running this command from the commandline on the vm itself, takes a few seconds to return the message.
The test however, returns in noticeable less time with an empty string.

Could anyone please shed some light on this? :)

Comment: The error is probably on stderr, not stdout.

Comment: I actually tried both stderr and stdout.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your test - `nptq`, but should be `ntpq`. Also `sudo` is not required in the test, as the test is already run as root.

Comment: Thank you both, apparently it was a combination of both. The typo obviously broke the command, and the result i was looking for was indeed defined in stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Error lies in:

```
control 'ntp configuration' do
  describe command('sudo nptq -p') do
    its('stdout') { should match('localhost: timed out, nothing received') }
  end
end
```

Typo in the command -> nptq has to be ntpq, also sudo can be omitted.

The message that was being checked for was actually returned in `stderr` instead of `stdout`

Working code:

```
  describe command 'ntpq -p' do
      its('stderr') { should match(/localhost: timed out, nothing received/) }
  end
```